# What is one word for "easily found"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need one word that replaces the short phrase "easily found", or something similar such as easily detected, identified, 
discovered, spotted, etc.

For example, "The relevant content was easily found on the page."

I realize this might be too vague, but maybe someone more creative than me has something.

Comment: Please add an example of how you intend to use the term(s), and describe what research you have done on your own. Otherwise this question is off-topic on EL&U. Thank you.

Comment: *easily-found*.

Answer (score 3):

You can say the object is *[conspicuous](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/conspicuous)*, meaning it is easy to notice.

Answer (score 1):

**"Findable**" or **"findability"** might work, depending on your context. For more information, see the article on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findability

Comment: Although,*findable* describes anything that can be found regardless of the difficulty involved.  For *findability* it must be coupled with a modifier: "high findability" or "low findability".

Answer (score -2):

Accessible or available perhaps? Depends on your sentence really.

Comment: It was my fault, I wasn't clear enough initially. I want one word to describe "high findability." One word to describe "easily found" in the sentence "The relevant content was easily found on the page."

Comment: Please fully explain why you would choose either word.